# How to get custom directive arguments in lighthouse graphql laravel

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

My question is regarding the custom directives
https://lighthouse-php.com/4.11/the-basics/directives.html#definition

My schema is:

```
type Query {
  sayFriendly: String @append(text: ", please.")
}
```

in lighthouse.php the config, I already have

```
'namespaces' => [
        'models' => ['App', 'App\\Models'],
        'queries' => 'App\\GraphQL\\Queries',
        'mutations' => 'App\\GraphQL\\Mutations',
        'subscriptions' => 'App\\GraphQL\\Subscriptions',
        'interfaces' => 'App\\GraphQL\\Interfaces',
        'unions' => 'App\\GraphQL\\Unions',
        'scalars' => 'App\\GraphQL\\Scalars',
        'directives' => ['App\\GraphQL\\Directives'],
    ],
```

directive enabled.

I defined the directive at \App\GraphQL\Directives\appendDirective as

```
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Directives;

use Closure;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\ResolveInfo;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Schema\Values\FieldValue;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Contracts\Directive;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Contracts\FieldMiddleware;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Contracts\GraphQLContext;

class appendDirective implements Directive, FieldMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Name of the directive as used in the schema.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function name(): string
    {
        return 'append';
    }

    /**
     * Wrap around the final field resolver.
     *
     * @param \Nuwave\Lighthouse\Schema\Values\FieldValue $fieldValue
     * @param \Closure $next
     * @return \Nuwave\Lighthouse\Schema\Values\FieldValue
     */
    public function handleField(FieldValue $fieldValue, Closure $next): FieldValue
    {

        // Retrieve the existing resolver function
        /** @var Closure $previousResolver */
        $previousResolver = $fieldValue->getResolver();

        // Wrap around the resolver
        $wrappedResolver = function ($root, array $args, GraphQLContext $context, ResolveInfo $info) use ($previousResolver): string {
            // Call the resolver, passing along the resolver arguments
            /** @var string $result */
            $result = $previousResolver($root, $args, $context, $info);
            return ($result);
        };

        // Place the wrapped resolver back upon the FieldValue
        // It is not resolved right now - we just prepare it
        $fieldValue->setResolver($wrappedResolver);

        // Keep the middleware chain going
        return $next($fieldValue);
    }

}
```

how can I get the value of key "text" from my directive and append to $result [ @append(text: ", please.") ].
The $args is an empty array (and It should be because I did make parameterized query [sayFriendly] )

Answer (score 4):

If you extend your directive from `Nuwave\Lighthouse\Schema\Directives\BaseDirective` you can have access to `$this->directiveArgValue('text');` to retrieve the text argument to your custom directive.

The `$args` are empty because that are the arguments supplied by the client in the query, in the `sayFriendly` query example there are no args possible so that will always be empty.

*As a tip: you can find this out by looking at an [already implemented directives](https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse/blob/b73a6f62eda4f6e002afaa0df73a4b62498bf832/src/Schema/Directives/CanDirective.php#L91) inside Lighthouse, the documentation is a bit thin on the custom directives but you can learn a lot by looking at the directives provided by Lighthouse.*